# Curl with SSL not working on ubuntu server

Tags: ssl, openssl, curl

When I try to Curl a SSL page on my ubuntu 12.04 TLS server, it won't work:

**not ssl page:**

```
$ curl https://evernote.com/ -vv
[the entire webpage]
```

**ssl page:**

```
$ curl https://evernote.com/ -vv
* About to connect() to evernote.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 204.154.94.73... connected
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to evernote.com:443 
* Closing connection #0
curl: (35) Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to evernote.com:443
```

This does work on my own machine (OS X).

When I try it via openSSL:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect evernote.com:433
connect: Connection timed out
connect:errno=110
```

openSSL version:

```
$ openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.1c 10 May 2012
```

Comment: If you are using cloud services.. then makes sense to check (with your cloud provider) if theres any proxy in between that could be dropping your connection

Comment: Another advice: check local time is correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You seem to have a typo.

```
$ openssl s_client -connect evernote.com:433
```

Port 433 is not open on the remote host, which is why you got error 110 (Connection refused).

Try using port 443 (the standard HTTPS port) instead.

---

As for curl, I can replicate the problem when using `evernote.com`, but `www.evernote.com` works properly (though it sends a 302 redirect to `https://evernote.com/`.

```
$ curl https://evernote.com/ -vv
* About to connect() to evernote.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 204.154.94.73...
* connected
* Connected to evernote.com (204.154.94.73) port 443 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* NSS error -5938 (PR_END_OF_FILE_ERROR)
* Encountered end of file
* Closing connection #0
curl: (35) Encountered end of file
```

This means that the server killed the connection. For whatever reason it really doesn't want to talk to us.

This is probably not something that you can fix.

Comment: The openssl command had a typo indeed. But my curl command gives a different error: `curl: (35) Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to evernote.com:443 `. The error disappears on https://google.com so I guess it's the server.

Comment: The errors seen here (with PR_END_OF_FILE_ERROR) are likely realted to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15773806/nss-client-certificate-not-found-nickname-not-specified

Comment: @EricRich There's no obvious relation between this and the post you linked. Please clarify.

Answer (score 1):

Had very similar problem - there was an issue in protocol negotiation, which probably led to some miscommunication with the crypto provider (OpenSSL libs). Try setting the secure protocol explicitly, e.g.:

```
curl --sslv3 # OR
curl --sslv2 # OR
curl --tlsv1
```